# What is the alternate to get the current Url in Asp.net core View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am currently migrating MVC Project to Asp.Net Core Project where in Layout page i used one piece of code to get the current base url.

e.g: If i run MVC application hosted in IIS server then i used Virtual directory to have the MVC application like below:

https://mydomain/myMVCApplication/Login

Then using below code in view i can get the Url till Virtual directory

https://mydomain/myMVCApplication/

```js
 var baseUrl = @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(new Uri(new Uri(this.Context.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), Url.Content("~/")).ToString(), true));
```

But when migrate in asp.net core view then Here Context.Request.Url where Url is not a property of Context.Request.

Please suggest here to fix above issue and get the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Asp.net Core application, you could try to get the URL using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest` class or the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions`. Then, using ViewData to store the URL in the action method, and display the url on the View Page.

1. Use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest` class

   ```
        ViewData["Message"] = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.PathBase}";
   ```

   or

   ```
        ViewData["Message"] = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.Path}";
   ```
2. Use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions

   Using the following code:

   ```
        var displayUrl = UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(Request);
        var urlBuilder =
        new UriBuilder(displayUrl)
        {
            Query = null,
            Fragment = null
        };
        string url = urlBuilder.ToString();
        ViewData["Message"] = url;
   ```

Code in the View page:

```
@{ 
    if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
    {
        @ViewData["Message"]
    }; 
}
```

Comment: this.Request.PathBase did the job using this i am getting the domain with Virtual directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetFullUrl(Request)

Comment: What is Request here? please explain.

Comment: Getting compile error: UriHelper does not contain a definition of GetFullUrl.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
@{
var baseUrl = HttpContext.Request.IsHttps ? $"https://{HttpContext.Request.Host}" : $"http:{HttpContext.Request.Host}"
}
```

Comment: curly braces inside double quotes is not providing the correct format. kindly modify your code and provide.

Comment: I am using string interpolation with $, curly braces should work, can you paste what error are you facing?

Comment: When i used the suggested code then i found like there was compilation error in HttpContext class. I added refrence in top of view inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor then used like this: var baseUrl = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.IsHttps ? $"https://{HttpContext.Request.Host}" : $"http:{HttpContext.Request.Host}" and getting console error: Unexpected string. this code i used inside javascript. Please have it checked.

Comment: Request.Host is providing only the domain name not with domain and virtual directory. Using Request.Host with Request.PathBase providing the correct result as expected.

Comment: HttpContext.Request.IsHttps can give you fake result in case you host an app behind load balancing. Better to use Request.Scheme.